# Invoking reflected case class constructor in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I can get the default constructor of a case class via static reflection thusly:

```
val symbol = currentMirror.classSymbol(myObj.getClass).typeSignature.typeSymbol.asClass
val ctor = symbol.primaryConstructor
```

From here I can do nifty things like introspect details of its fields, etc.  But how can I now invoke the constructor method?  I could dig into myObj's class, but if it has multiple constructors, is there a straightforward way to match the right constructor to the one I got from primaryConstructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `reflectConstructor` method on the class mirror:

```
val classMirror = currentMirror.reflectClass(typeOf[Foo].typeSymbol.asClass)
classMirror.reflectConstructor(ctor.asMethod).apply(2, "bar").asInstanceOf[Foo]
```