# Invoking reflected case class constructor in Scala, Part 2

Tags: scala, reflection

This question is a follow-on to this one: [Invoking Case Class Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686227/invoking-reflected-case-class-constructor-in-scala)

The answer I selected works great--except for a few cases involving value classes.  In these cases I try code like this:

```
// cc.ctor is an reflected MethodMirror as described in linked question.
println(s"::: Poof: ${cc.name} with "+args.toList)
println("--- Ctor : "+cc.ctor)  
println("--- Args : "+args.toList.map(_.getClass.getName))
println("--- Tried: "+scala.util.Try( cc.ctor.apply(args:_*) ))
```

The objects involved are below.  Wrapped is the object being constructed.

```
case class Wrapped( hey:Wrapper, you:String )
class Wrapper(val underlying: String) extends AnyVal
```

Here's the output I get:

```
::: Poof: co.blocke.scalajack.test.v4.Wrapped with List(co.blocke.scalajack.test.v4.Wrapper@18cc6, greg)
--- Ctor : constructor mirror for def <init>(hey: co.blocke.scalajack.test.v4.Wrapper,you: String): co.blocke.scalajack.test.v4.Wrapped (bound to null)
--- Args : List(co.blocke.scalajack.test.v4.Wrapper, java.lang.String)
--- Tried: Success(Wrapped(co.blocke.scalajack.test.v4.Wrapper@18cc6,null))
```

Sooo close!  You can see in the last line the Wrapped object, including its member value class, is "successfully" created, but where's my String?  The constructor expects one.  I passed one in in the args, but I get a big, fat null in my object.  What's going on?

Adding gist here to demonstrate problem: [See Code](https://gist.github.com/gzoller/9158363115a6bcd646f5)